# Ajax not working on list items within unordered list

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm beginner in programming. I tried to used Ajax on unordered list to run the list item (li) id like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordion li").not('.empty').click(function() {
            var addr = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: addr,
                type: "GET",
                data: dataString,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert('I would run those addr here . ' + addr);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <ul id="accordion">
        <li id="a1.php"><a href="#">Aaa</a></li>
        <li class="empty"><a href="#">Bbb</a></li>
        <li class="empty"><a href="#">Ccc</a></li>
        <li class="empty"><a href="#">Ddd</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

This code above doesn't work, why ?

Comment: what is `dataString` ?

Comment: you have not set any value in `dataString` variable hence javascript is trigging an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion li").not('.empty').click(function() {
        var addr = $(this).attr('id');
        var dataString = "some string";
        $.ajax({
            url: addr,
            type: "GET",
            data: dataString,
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('I would run those addr here . ' + addr);
            }
        });
    });
});
```